# Как перезапустить aiohttp сервер на Python для обновления SSL_context

Tags: python, ssl, asyncio

Есть вот такая функция, которая запускает сервер.
Проблема - через 90 дней сертификаты протухают и обновляються автоматически, и мне нужно перезагрузить их в мою программу, но всю программу перезапускать недопустимо, нужно либо как-то подсунуть серверу новые сертификаты, либо перезапустить только сервер, какие варианты есть для решения данной проблемы?

```
def run(self, port, host, loop):
    self.app = web.Application()
    self.app.router.add_post('/', self.bot.handler)

    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile=self.cert, keyfile=self.keyfile)

    web.run_app(self.app, host=host, port=port, ssl_context=context, loop=loop)
```

Comment: Ну передавайте вместо context прокси с блокировкой на время обновления. В чем проблема то? В конкретной реализации? Если в конкретной реализации, то для ответа нужен примерный код вашего класса и функции self.app

Comment: вот реализация self.app - (http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/aiohttp/web.html)
это не мой класс

Comment: ну и как обновить , я не знаю как это сделать, поэтому и задал вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется вэб сервер перезапускать не нужно.

Прицепи [ssl контекст](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext) к приложению или уложи куда-нибудь ссылку, чтоб можно было достать его:

```
self.context = context
```

Когда придет время загрузи в него новую цепочку той же [командой](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain):

```
self.context.load_cert_chain(certfile=self.cert, keyfile=self.keyfile)
```

Я бы повесил на [сигнал](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) `signal.SIGHUP`.

Comment: Кстати да, Спасибо!